# ZF2 sql count rows with different values

Tags: sql, count, zend-framework2

I'm developing an application in zend framework 2 ans need to get some count values from a database table. 
the table contains members with a column 'active' and 'blocked'

i would like te get the total number of members as well as the number of active and the number of blocked members.

Note that there will be a big amount of members in the table, so 'slow solutions' are not a option.

thanx for the help!

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: A tip: you should make a column "state" and set it to active or blocked, then you can group/count on it.

Comment: is active / blocked a value of 0 or 1 or does it contain something else?

Comment: they are both 0/1, changing them to one column 'state' is not really an option 'cause that would mean i have to change a lot of code in different controllers. The solution you provided works perfectlyas like i wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With those 2 columns, you would need to do something like:

```
SELECT SUM(active) as nrActive, SUM(if(blocked = 'yes', 1, 0)) as nrBlocked FROM members;
```

In this example "active" can have value 0 or 1, for blocked I assumed 'yes' and 'no', this way you have an example of both situations.

In ZF2 you can compose a query using Zend\Sql

```
$sql = new \Zend\Db\Sql($dbAdapter);
$sql->from('members', array(
    'nrActive'  => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('SUM(active)'),
    'nrBlocked' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('SUM(if(blocked = "yes", 1, 0))')
);
```

(disclaimer: I wrote this off hand so can have typo's, just for example)